# Weka model Read Error in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, machine-learning, weka

I created my weka model in the machine and imported it to the  android project. When i try to create the classifier it gives an error "exception.java.io.StreamCorruptedException" when i try to deserialise the model i created. The code perfectly works in machine.

This is my Code,

```
InputStream fis = null;

        fis = new InputStream("/modle.model");

        InputStream is = fis;

        Classifier cls = null;

       //here im getting the error when trying to read the Classifier
            cls = (Classifier) SerializationHelper.read(is);

        FileInputStream datais = null;

            datais = new FileInputStream("/storage/emulated/0/window.arff");


        InputStream dataIns = datais;
        DataSource source = new DataSource(dataIns);
        Instances data = null;
        try {
            data = source.getDataSet();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        data.setClassIndex(data.numAttributes() - 1);

        Instance in = new Instance(13);
        in.setDataset(data);
        in.setValue(0, testWekaModle1[0]);
        in.setValue(1, testWekaModle1[1]);
        in.setValue(2, testWekaModle1[2]);
        in.setValue(3, testWekaModle1[3]);
        in.setValue(4, testWekaModle1[4]);
        in.setValue(5, testWekaModle1[5]);
        in.setValue(6, testWekaModle1[6]);
        in.setValue(7, testWekaModle1[7]);
        in.setValue(8, testWekaModle1[8]);
        in.setValue(9, testWekaModle1[9]);
        in.setValue(10, testWekaModle1[10]);
        in.setValue(11, testWekaModle1[11]);

        double value = 0;

            value = cls.classifyInstance(in);

        in.setClassValue(value);
```

This is the full stacktrace,

```
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:2109)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:372)
weka.core.SerializationHelper.read(SerializationHelper.java:288)
info.androidhive.sleepApp.model.ControllerWeka.wekaModle(ControllerWeka.java:81)
info.androidhive.sleepApp.activity.HomeFragment.extract(HomeFragment.java:278)
info.androidhive.sleepApp.activity.HomeFragment.stop(HomeFragment.java:146)
"info.androidhive.sleepApp.activity.HomeFragment$2.onClick(HomeFragment.java:107)"
android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4475)"
android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18786)"
android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)"
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)"
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1025)"
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1209)"
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)"
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)"
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)"
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)"
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)"
```

Please help me to overcome this problem.

Comment: the issue was sold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is resolved, the model was created in a different environment(PC) and tried to deserialise in the android environment which gave error because of the two types of JDK wasn't same at all.

Comment: So is it possible to use a .model file directly from the Weka GUI? Or do we have to train it on Android?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that both of the weka.jar have the same version.
And do NOT use the GUI version of Weka to save the model since the Android runtime does not contain GUI related packages used by weka.

It would be fine that build and save the model programmatically with desktop and deserialise it through Android.